# Error Query completed with an empty output

Tags: google-sheets

=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I57M2dP-q_fL5YCNJwAxPmkmdPV1e8SoESWvYGhsfW4/edit#gid=0%22,%22PROCESS REJECT!A3:N"),"select Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col8,Col11 where Col3 = **'"&A1&"'")) I am trying to get the data from this cell that acts like a search bar and output that data in this sheet**

**I am trying to get the data from this cell that acts like a search bar and output that data i**[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOqCt.png)**n this** [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQZHS.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this out:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1I57M2dP-q_fL5YCNJwAxPmkmdPV1e8SoESWvYGhsfW4","PROCESS REJECT!A3:N"),"select Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col8,Col11 where Col3 = "&A1&""))
```

Answer (score 0):

first use:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("1I57M2dP-q_fL5YCNJwAxPmkmdPV1e8SoESWvYGhsfW4"; "PROCESS REJECT!A3")
```

connect your sheets and then use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(
 "1I57M2dP-q_fL5YCNJwAxPmkmdPV1e8SoESWvYGhsfW4"; "PROCESS REJECT!A3:N");
 "select Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col8,Col11 where Col3 = "&A1*1; ))
```

this will work only if your column C is numeric. you can check this like:

```
=ISNUMBER(IMPORTRANGE("1I57M2dP-q_fL5YCNJwAxPmkmdPV1e8SoESWvYGhsfW4"; "PROCESS REJECT!C3"))
```

Comment: I also want that particular cell to act as a search box that will accept any data type, like text, numeric, and date

Comment: =ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I57M2dP-q_fL5YCNJwAxPmkmdPV1e8SoESWvYGhsfW4","PROCESS REJECT!A3:N"),"select Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col8,Col11 where Col2 or Col3 or Col4 Or Col5 = "&I1&""))

Comment: these columns are numeric text and date data types

Comment: @Vince so your Col3 is with a mixed dataset (numeric numbers, plain text and dates)?